# how to call a JQuery function inside an ajax callback function

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript

I have a custom module, this module has a form with an ajax submit callback

```
$form['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'submit',
'#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'mymodule_submit_driven_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'box',
),
'#value' => t('Submit'),
);
```

I into the callback function I need to call a JQuery function:

```
function mymodule_submit_driven_callback($form, $form_state) {
//call JQuery function here
}
```

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Jose Daniel said: use ajax_command_invoke() in your ajax callback:

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, "your_function");
$output = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
ajax_deliver($output);
```

Your JS-File:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.your_function = function() {
      // do cool stuff
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: There is no need to warp the code that define additional functions on `$.fn` in a `$(document).ready(...)`, unless definition of these functions actually requires the DOM document to be ready.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking a question by proposing an answer ... Why again do you need to call a jQuery function from within in your callback?

Normally in D7 the ajax callback function creates a list of `Commands` to send back to the client and perform client side javascript using jQuery.

Did you read up on the [Ajax framework used by Drupal](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7)?

> #ajax['callback']: The callback to invoke to handle the server side of the Ajax event, which will receive a $form and $form_state as
>   arguments, and returns a renderable array (most often a form or form
>   fragment), an HTML string, or an array of Ajax commands. If returning
>   a renderable array or a string, the value will replace the original
>   element named in #ajax['wrapper'], and theme_status_messages() will be
>   prepended to that element. (If the status messages are not wanted,
>   return an array of Ajax commands instead.) #ajax['wrapper']. If an
>   array of Ajax commands is returned, it will be executed by the calling
>   code.

EDIT:

Also see the [Ajax Examples in the Developer Examples module](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example.module/group/ajax_example/7).

Comment: I need to make a call because I need to update some things in the look and feel of the website.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using [ajax_command_invoke()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/function/ajax_command_invoke/7).